# How do I remove the last newline character in a text in Python?

Tags: python, replace, newline, strip, blank-line

I have a program that decodes a caesar cipher and a few text files with multiple lines to decode.

There is always a blank line after the text according to my lecturers code checker, but I don't see anything when I run the code myself.

Removing the last character only removes the last letter or number in the text and not the newline.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
import string
import collections

ciphertext_lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
ciphertext = ''

for i in ciphertext_lines:
    ciphertext += i

alphanum = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'



def getShiftVal():

    string = ''

    for line in ciphertext:
        string = string + line

    most_common_letter = ((collections.Counter(string).most_common(2)[1])[0])

    shift_val = (alphanum.index(most_common_letter) - 4)

    return shift_val



def decrypt(ciphertext, n):

    alphabet_numbers = collections.deque(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)

    alphanum = ''.join(list(alphabet_numbers))

    alphabet_numbers.rotate(n)

    alphanum_rotated = ''.join(list(alphabet_numbers))

    return ciphertext.translate(str.maketrans(alphanum, alphanum_rotated))



def main():

    n = getShiftVal()

    decrypted = decrypt(ciphertext, n)

    print(decrypted)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

`print` by default adds a newline after its output.  Under Python 2, use `print decrypted,` (note the trailing comma) to suppress the trailing newline.  Under Python 3, use `print(decrypted, end='')`.  Or, alternatively, you can just use `sys.stdout.write(decrypted)` to write the output without any formatting.